# BibTeX: Help in modifying .bst style file requested

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am using BibTeX for my bibliography and everything works as expected. For formatting output I am using natdin, which does almost exactly what I want, except for one or two small things:

It uses `--` to denote page ranges, and I'd like to have a spatium before and after the dash, i.e. use `\,--\,`. When I look into the .bst file, I find this:

```
FUNCTION {n.dashify}
{ 't :=
  ""
    { t empty$ not }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" =
        { t #1 #2 substring$ "--" = not
            { "--" *
              t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
            }
            {   { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" = }
                { "-" *
                  t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
                }
              while$
            }
          if$
        }
        { t #1 #1 substring$ *
          t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
        }
      if$
    }
  while$
}
```

Unfortunately I have no idea what this does, exactly, or how to modify it in order to accomplish what I am looking for.

So here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \section{Lorem Ispum}
        According to \citet{Nescio.2000} we find that 
        \lipsum[1]

    \bibliography{test}
    \bibliographystyle{natdin} 
\end{document}
```

The accompanying test.bib file contains

```
@article{Nescio.2000,
 author = {Nescio, Nomen and Public, John Q. and Else, Somebody},
 year = {2000},
 title = {What Miscellaneous Anomaly is This? A Field Guide for the Utterly Confused},
 pages = {95--105},
 volume = {08/15},
 journal = {Internationale Zeitschrift für Tetrapilotomie und Potiosektion}
 }
```

natdin is widely available on CTAN and used as is.

As you can see in the rendered example, I get `S. 95-105` when I really want `S.~95\,--\,105`.

Comment: Either you are using standard BibTeX, and editing a `.bst` file makes sense, or `biblatex`, where you can't edit the `.bst` file but rather alter things in LaTeX. Which is it?

Comment: What happens if you replace `{ "--" *` by `{ "\,--\," *`? (Of course, you do not modify the original style, but copy the file, rename it and change the lines as suggested above.)

Comment: It is quite confusing that you state you use `biblatex` and then refer to `natdin` which is a BibTeX style. Your example snippet is the content of a `.bst` file though, so I assume you use BibTeX and not `biblatex`. If you do use `biblatex` you really should not load `natdin` or any `.bst` file for that matter.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it's actually BibTeX. (Can you tell I'm only starting to get the hang of it all?)

Comment: @moewe: Not working, I've actually tried that. Not that the code makes much sense to me, but this just seems to be a condition (not) to be met.

Comment: OK, can you prepare a short [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/), so we can have a proper stab at the question?

Comment: I have updated my original question with an MWE.

Comment: @moewe The simple fix you suggest doesn't work, since the `.bst` treats bib entries with `pages={n--m}` differently from entries with `pages={n-m}`. The change you suggest will work if the bib entries are like the latter, but not the former.

Comment: Changing `pages = {95--105},` to `pages = {95\,--\,105},` in the .bib file adds the spatiums you wanted. If you have few enough that adding them manually is not an issue, that should suffice.

Comment: While this does in fact work, I'd rather not add markup or other typographic information to the .bib file. It's also created automatically, and I'd have to redo it every time. Sure, a script could do it, but this is just cumbersome. In that light, I could simply edit the .bbl file directly, but I feel there must be some way to address this issue in the style file.

Comment: @SnoringFrog This is a super last resort solution which will break the bib file for any other use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `n.dashify` function is used for both page number ranges and other elements like ISBN numbers, so in order to get the style to work the way you want, we need to separate out those two uses in the style.  The simplest way to do this is to create a version of the function for page ranges (which we will call `n.dashify`) and create a new version (like the previous `n.dashify` which we will call `n.dashify.plain`. Additionally, we need to change the functions that process non-page number ranges to use the `n.dashify.plain` function instead of our new function.

First, make a copy of `natdin.bst` and put it in your local `texmf` folder (on a TeX Live system this is usually `~/texmf/tex/bibtex/bst` (`~/Library/texmf/tex/bibtex/bst` on a Mac)).

Then, make a copy of the original `n.dashify` function in the file and give it a new name:  `n.dashify.plain`

Next, replace the old `n.dashify` function with the following one:

```
FUNCTION {n.dashify}
{ 't :=
  ""
    { t empty$ not }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" =
        { t #1 #2 substring$ "--" = not
            { "\,--\," *
              t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
            }
            {   { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" = }
                { "" *
                  t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
                }
              while$
             "\,--\," * }
          if$
        }
        { t #1 #1 substring$ *
          t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
        }
      if$
    }
  while$
}
```

You should now have two `n.dashify` type functions in the `.bst` file: `n.dashify` and `n.dashify.plain`.

Finally, change the following two functions (which format URLs and ISSN/ISBNs) to use the `n.dashify.plain` function:

```
FUNCTION { format.doi.urn }
{ urn empty$
     { doi empty$
          { "" }
          { "DOI" doi n.dashify.plain tie.or.space.connect }
       if$
     }
     { "URN" urn n.dashify.plain tie.or.space.connect }
  if$
}

FUNCTION { format.isbn.issn }
{ isbn empty$
     { issn empty$
          { "" }
          { "ISSN" issn n.dashify.plain tie.or.space.connect }
       if$
     }
     { "ISBN" isbn n.dashify.plain tie.or.space.connect }
  if$
}
```

Here's a sample document.  I've duplicated the bib entries to show the behaviour with pages entries of the form `n--m` and `n-m` in the `.bib` file (see discussion in the comments above) and added some ISBN numbers to check that things work as expected.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Nescio.2000,
 author = {Nescio, Nomen and Public, John Q. and Else, Somebody},
 year = {2000},
 title = {What Miscellaneous Anomaly is This? A Field Guide for the Utterly Confused},
 pages = {95--105},
 volume = {08/15},
 journal = {Internationale Zeitschrift für Tetrapilotomie und Potiosektion},
 isbn = {1-84356-028-3}
 }
@article{Nescio.2000b,
 author = {Nescio, Nomen and Public, John Q. and Else, Somebody},
 year = {2000},
 title = {What Miscellaneous Anomaly is This? A Field Guide for the Utterly Confused},
 pages = {95-105},
 volume = {08/15},
 journal = {Internationale Zeitschrift für Tetrapilotomie und Potiosektion},
 issn = {1-84356-028-3}
 }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \section{Lorem Ispum}
        According to \citet{Nescio.2000b,Nescio.2000} we find that 
        \lipsum[1]

    \bibliography{\jobname}
    \bibliographystyle{natdin-copy} 
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I have tested this with a full .bib and it works (almost) as expected, the exception being single dashes (such as in ISBN, e.g.) that are now converted to `\,--\,` as well. I have checked my source, and page numbers will always and reliably be used with `--` only, i.e. 95--105. That said, unless this is trivial to fix (and, seriously, what ever is?) I am more than happy with and thankful for the solution provided.

Comment: @Ingmar I thought that might be a problem. It's not too diffucult to fix.  I'll update the answer later this evening.

Comment: @Ingmar I've updated the answer to fix the ISBN issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I've been trying to accomplish. You, sir, are a a scholar and a gentleman :-)